# Navigation Controller doesn't appear on Dashboard ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I am using a Navigation Controller in Xcode8, the navigation bar doesn't appear on the following View Controller on the Dashboard. They will appear on the simulator and on the ViewController topDown tree, but nothing on the view of the dashboard.

[Navigation Controller Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hc8xf.png)

Comment: It is as designed, it is unclear why are you trying to do with it.

Comment: With the nav controller, the nav bar should appear in the followings view in the dashboard (here it is not the case). We can see the nav bar in the top-down tree and in the simulator, but it disappeared from the dashboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the segue before the Navigation Controller. When I delete it, all the Navigation Bar come back. Don't know why, but if the problem happen, you just have to delete this segue and then with Ctrl+Z, the segue come back and the nav bar stay

Answer (score 0):

Its'a strange problem, It always happen to me too. You can change your segue type to deprecated `Push` to see nav bar, after that you can change again.

When you connect your navigation controller to the view controller it happens, because it creates segue type to Show. When you change the segue type to Push segue, you can see the Nav Bar on your View Controller.

Just click the segue, you should see the segue options on the right like the picture.

[image]

Comment: Thank's for your answer, which one do you change ? We can't change type of the segue directly after the navigation view, and when I switch twice the type of segues before the navigation view and after the fist View Controller, nothing happen.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I see what you mean, after trying and trying, it didn't came back. In my case the Nav Bar appears well at the first Time. When I close/open my project that the nav bar disappear on the dashboard. after changing the segue Type as you've mentioned, nothing change.